# How should the Bollen-Stine bootstrap $p$-value be calculated?

Tags: bootstrap, structural-equation-modeling

Writing about an original test statistic $T_{ML}$, Nevitt and Hancock (2001) write on p356 that

> The bootstrap-adjusted $p$ value is calculated as the proportion of
> bootstrap model test statistics that exceed the value of $T_{ML}$
> obtained from the original parent sample.

This calculation would seem to not include the original test-statistic. Rather, it would divide the number of bootstrapped test statistics with worse fit by the total number of bootstrapped test statistics.

However, talking about a situation in which “The model fit better in 263 bootstrap samples. It fit about equally well in 0 bootstrap samples. It fit worse or failed to fit in 237 bootstrap samples” [the AMOS support page says](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/calculation-bollen-stine-significance-value-amos)

> In your example, the Bollen-Stine $p$ is computed as p = 238/501. The
> reasoning is that you have 501 chi square values. You know that 500 of
> them were generated randomly. The null hypothesis is that all 501 were
> generated randomly. If they were, then the question is, what is the
> probability that the original chi square value (i.e., the one from the
> original sample) would have rank number of 238 or less after ranking
> all 501 chi square values.

Thus AMOS does include the original test statistic in the calculation.

Which way is better? Why?

Nevitt, J., & Hancock, G. R. (2001). Performance of bootstrapping approaches to model test statistics and parameter standard error estimation in structural equation modeling. Structural equation modeling, 8(3), 353-377.

Comment: I suspect you'd be better off asking this in a community that specializes in SEM  (like semnet). It's pretty obscure.